# Producing dynamic html from a json in angularjs

Tags: json, html, angularjs

I have this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AtcW0QHPa54WKIVXUOE6?p=preview) in which i have a json object which is nested in `angularjs`.

I am using bootstrap `navbar` to make a menu out of this json. I am stuck at this point. How do i Parse a highly nested JSON object which represents a navigation menu and produce syntactically correct and dynamic HTML for displaying the menu?

Comment: What are you actually trying to extract?

Comment: I am trying to put the name like john, doe in nav-pills and put the nested data in dropdowns. So the html should create multiple dropdowns for more nested data. i just updated the plunk a bit :)

Comment: It would be helpful if we knew the desired output, but i guess `ng-repeat` could do the job. btw: It's an object, not a JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

I [forked](http://plnkr.co/edit/AtcW0QHPa54WKIVXUOE6?p=preview) your plunker. Does that show more or less what you are looking to do?

The general idea is you assign something (a value, array or object) to `$scope` so the controller can access it. Then you bind data to the view (aka the HTML document) by assigning the controller to a document element. Once this is done you can use the standard javascript `object.property` syntax in combination with the `{{}}` syntax and `ng-repeat` to access element and array values.